# Octave least squares approximation

Tags: octave

So i've got a task.
That's here:

> What values does the model `F (t) = x(1) + x(2)*t^2 + x(3)*sin(π*t)`
>   best fit in the least squares sense of the following data take place
>   at 1.0? t=[0.1 0.3 0.4 0.8 0.9] f=[2.06 2.91 3.19 3.16 2.89]

```
t=[0.1 0.3 0.4 0.8 0.9]';
f=[2.06 2.91 3.19 3.16 2.89]';
A=[ones(5,1),sin(pi*t)];
x=(A'*A)\(A'*f)
xx=linspace(0,1.0);
yy=x(1)+x(2).*xx.^2+x(3).*sin(pi.*xx);
figure; plot(t,f,'*',xx,yy)
```

I wrote this code and got an error 
 called from
    *code.m(example)* at line 6 column 3

Comment: What is the error. What does it say.  Which is line 6? Its part of coding to be able to read error messages. Please post it in full if you need help.

Comment: Do you know that x has dimensions (2,1) so x(3) does not exist ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `pinv` to solve `x`, i.e.,

```
m = [t.^0;t.^2;sin(pi*t)];
x = f*pinv(m);
```

such that

```
>> x
x =

   1.5760   1.0504   1.5286
```

**Data**

```
t=[0.1 0.3 0.4 0.8 0.9];
f=[2.06 2.91 3.19 3.16 2.89];
```